# I want to display different divs by clicking buttons

Tags: jquery, html, css

This is my code for the buttons, I want them to display a corresponding div with each button click. I understand I need to use jquery to do this? Not sure how. Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

```
/* ~~ buttons start here ~~ */

a.about, a.sketches, a.vectors, a.misc, a.contact {
    display:block;
    margin-left: 72px;
    margin-bottom: 45px;
}

a.about {
    width: 100px;
    height: 20px;
    background-image: url("about.png");
}

a.about:hover {
    background-image: url("about_invert.png");
}

a.about:active {
    background-image: url("about.png");
}

a.sketches {
    width: 134px;
    height: 20px;
    background-image: url("sketches.png");
}

a.sketches:hover {
    background-image: url("sketches_invert.png");
}

a.sketches:active {
    background-image: url("sketches.png");
}

a.vectors {
    width: 125px;
    height: 20px;
    background-image: url("vectors.png");
}

a.vectors:hover {
    background-image: url("vectors_invert.png");
}

a.vectors:active {
    background-image: url("vectors.png");
}

a.misc {
    width: 74px;
    height: 20px;
    background-image: url("misc.png");
}

a.misc:hover {
    background-image: url("misc_invert.png");
}

a.misc:active {
    background-image: url("misc.png");
}

a.contact {
    width: 137px;
    height: 20px;
    background-image: url("contact.png");
}

a.contact:hover {
    background-image: url("contact_invert.png");
}

a.contact:active {
    background-image: url("contact.png");
}   

/* ~~ buttons end here ~~ */

<a href="#" class="about"></a>
<a href="#" class="sketches"></a>
<a href="#" class="vectors"></a>
<a href="#" class="misc"></a>
<a href="#" class="contact"></a>
```

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_install.asp

Comment: That's CSS and HTML. Where is your JS code?

Comment: Buttons...? all i can find is css and hyperlinks. and wehre's the respective divs..?!!

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_hide_show.asp

Comment: It looks like you haven't even searched this on Google, because just typing "Jquery Show/Hide DIV" would pop up hundreds of examples..

Comment: For all those quoting w3schools please visit http://w3fools.com

Comment: I can't get my head around how it would work unless it's specific to my code.

Comment: You won't learn anything by being spoon-fed answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the same class as the `<a>` tag in the correspondent `<div>` tag and call them by class:

```
$('a').on('click',function(){
   $('div.' + $(this).attr('class')).each(function(){
       if($(this).is(':visible')){
           $('div').hide();
       } else {
           $('div').hide();
           $(this).show();
       }

   });
});
```

Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/vWT5t/1/